# For a linear system Ax = b where the entries of A are real numbers and A is 17 × 17, it’s possible for the system to have exactly seventeen solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this true/false question on a practice exam.

```
For a linear system Ax = b where the entries of A are real numbers and A is 17 × 17, it’s
possible for the system to have exactly seventeen solutions.
```

So I'm saying False because it can only have unique, infinite or no solutions in R^n. But i would like to hear other opinions on this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You are correct.${}$

Comment: Another thing is that: The question says the entries are real numbers but that doesn't necessarily say anything about the field. The field could be in Z^n. which in that case the statement could actually be true? What are your thoughts on this.

Comment: @AA Yeah, in fact $A$ and $b$ could be zero and the field could be any seventeen element subset of $\mathbb R^{17}$. No, not really ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no other opinions. $Ax=b$ has either a unique solution, or no solution or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: In R^n but in Z^n its possible to have 17 solutions. The question says the entries are real numbers but the system itself could be in Z^n.

Comment: So this question need not be closed as "primarily opinion-based" :)

Comment: @AA Even for integer solutions: If $x_1,x_2$ are solutions, then so is $x_1+k(x_2-x_1)$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.